# Failure in append items asynchronously in collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I' using Alamofire to build a pinterest-like layout.

and I followed [uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) here to build a pinterest-like layout. when I wanna to  implementing this with photos that are downloaded asynchronously, and it failde.

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData
>   layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]

```
Alamofire.request(Unicooo.Router.ReadPostList("",["act_id": self.actId, "page": self.currentPage])).validate().responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                let JSON = response.result.value
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let photoInfos =  ((JSON as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("results") as! [NSDictionary]).map {
                        PostPhotoInfo(id: ($0["id"] as! Int), title: ($0["post_title"] as! String)...)
                    }

                    let lastItem = self.postPhotos.count
                    self.postPhotos.addObjectsFromArray(photoInfos)
                    let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.postPhotos.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0)}
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths) // Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1.
                    }
                }
```

This works well when I set Main.storyboard collection view layout as Flow,but when I use custom flow like this:

```
private var cache = Dictionary<NSIndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()  //I change cache to Dictionary
override func prepareLayout() {
        if cache.isEmpty {
            let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
            var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
            for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
                xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth )
            }
            var column = 0
            var yOffset = [CGFloat](count: numberOfColumns, repeatedValue: 0)

            for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {

                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)

                let width = columnWidth - cellPadding * 2
                let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath,
                    withWidth:width)
                let annotationHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!,
                    heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)
                let height = cellPadding +  photoHeight + annotationHeight + cellPadding

                let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
                insetFrame = CGRectInset(frame, cellPadding, cellPadding)

                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = insetFrame!
                cache[indexPath] = attributes  //I change this line

                contentHeight = max(contentHeight, CGRectGetMaxY(frame))
                yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

                column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
            }
        }
    }

    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for (_, attributes) in cache {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect) {
                layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
```

As I search every thing about collection view in google: I tried to add this method:

```
override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        let attributes = cache[indexPath]
        return attributes
    }
```

But still can't work.I think this may relate to layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath did not return the correction attributes.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: please explain your issue a bit more

Comment: @Aison were you able to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I faced the same issue.
You also need to override the `invalidateLayout` method.

```
override func invalidateLayout() {
    cache.removeAll()
    super.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Then you need to call the invalidateLayout method just before the call to `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`

You need to clear your cache because the logic inside the `prepareLayout` method is called only if the cache is empty. As the layout has already been prepared and the cache filled then the new layout attributes aren't calculated and stored in the cache.